# ST:TNG episode with the Glass & Blue Gel Navigation device

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, episode-identification

I'm trying to remember which episode it is.

I remember Data checking it out on the bridge.
It didn't have navigational coordinates, as such, but something like pulsar rotation speeds.
It was a glass thermos-like device with a silver end connection and some wires at one end.
Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean "It didn't have navigational coordinates, as such"? You mean like a display?

Comment: Are you sure it was TNG? Voyager used "bio-neural gel-packs" as computer components. [They pretty similar to what you describe](http://vignette1.wikia.nocookie.net/memoryalpha/images/f/f2/Gel_pack_in_messhall.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20050813043800&path-prefix=en).

Comment: Accept the answer, don't post another answer saying that it is correct.

Answer (score 21):

It sounds like you are talking about the device from John Doe's ship in the third-season episode "[Transfigurations](http://www.st-minutiae.com/resources/scripts/173.txt)". Data and LaForge analyze it to try to determine Doe's place of origin, as he has no memory of it.

> **DATA:** Computer, assume these symbols are pulsars. Translate associated values into standard temporal notations.
>
> Computer, is there a **pulsar with a rotational period**
>   of...one-point-five-two-four-four seconds within sensor range?

[image]

Comment: A pulsar that completes a full spin in less than 2 seconds... Sure, Star Trek. Sure.

Comment: @jpmc26: I'm not a physicist (nor am I trying to defend ST's "science") but ["Most pulsars rotate just a few times per second, but some spin hundreds of times faster. These so-called millisecond pulsars whip around so quickly because they are thought to have stripped mass – and angular momentum – from companion stars at some point in their histories."](https://www.newscientist.com/article/dn8576-fast-spinning-neutron-star-smashes-speed-limit/) Seems that they're looking for a slowly spinning pulsar rather than an unusually fast one.

Comment: @jpmc26: https://wikipedia.org/wiki/PSR_J1748-2446ad Fastest spinning known pulsar, spinning at 714Hz (rotational period 1.39ms). The equator is moving at a quarter of the speed of light!

Comment: That is not nearly as fast as I imagined after all. I stand corrected.

Comment: I actually thought 1.52 seconds was way *too slow*, but WP says that the longest known pulsar period is 8.51 s referring to [a 1999 Nature paper](https://dx.doi.org/10.1038%2F23650) (before that it was thought it had a 2.84 s period, so maybe the ST writers bothered to look up pulsar periods)

Comment: @NickT Knowing their target audience, they strived (especially in the later seasons) to be as accurate as was reasonable on their budget.

Comment: My typical problem is with distances, which are far more common, though.

Answer (score 9):

Is this it?

[image: Data with device]

It's from the episode Contagion (2x11)

Comment: Good answer, but probably not :-)